# IntelliJ keeps folding my code by default

Tags: intellij-idea, folding

When I open up any code file .java or .html IntelliJ (12.x)  keeps the code folded and I always have to expand everything.

How do I make code expand by default?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the preferences (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> on my machine), under `Editor`, you will find an entry called `Code Folding`. In there you can choose what's folded by default. In your case, you'll probably want to remove all the defaults.

[image]

Comment: idea doesn't respect these settings for me. I have "Method bodies" deselected, yet, all method bodies in files that I open are closed by default.

Comment: This isn't likely -- idea actually works fine and nobody else has this as a problem, therefore you're doing something wrong. Usually it's as simple as committing your .idea folder to git, and having it rewritten every time you do a pull. Teams do this whenever they want to share ide configuration.

Comment: nope.. nothing like that.. I discovered, there's another setting for simple methods.. which was selected.. so getters/setters were folded for me, which I wanted to not be folded.

Comment: For me, the solution was:
Editor > General > Code Folding > General >  untick:  "File header"