# How do I remove this from IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I dont know what to call this "issue" thats why I cant google it, dont know what to search for. I guess it is a setting in IntelliJ so I uploaded two pictures, so the first picture is how it is everytime I restart me IDE Intellij and picture 2 is how I want it without edit it every time, I hope you understand, thank you!

[image: This is how it is now]

[image: This is how I want it]

Comment: how are we supposed to understand anything of this? don't post images, post actual code. Post all the code needed to explain your issue, also post the actual error (message) you get

Comment: its not code related its how the code is organized,. I want the return code on a new line like in the second picture but everytime I restart IntelliJ the return line is back on one line like in picture 1, there is no error or something wrong with the code itself......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ keeps folding my code by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083679/intellij-keeps-folding-my-code-by-default)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552079/disable-code-folding-in-intellij-idea/34552107

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as "[Code Folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html)". In the settings, go to Editor -> General -> Code Folding to disable folding by default.

[image]

In your screenshot specifically, it's the folding of "one line methods".